# Derivative of a function and its partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{p}$ open and $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{q}$. If D$f(x)$ exists for all $x \in \Omega$, and if i=1,2,...,q; j=1,2,...,p, then show that $|D_jf_i(x)-D_jf_i(y)|\leq ||Df(x)-Df(y)||_{pq}$. So, if $f$ belongs to the class $C^1(\Omega)$, then each one of the parcial derivatives $D_jf_i$ is continuos in $\Omega$.

- $||f||_{pq}=$sup$\{||f(x)||:x \in \mathbb{R}^p, ||x||\leq 1\}$

It's a problem of book (Elementos de Análise Real - Bartle) I'm using to study... But I just don't know what to do here... If someone could give a solution or a hint, it would be really helpfull...

Comment: Which norm do you take on the right-hand side? The notation "pq" does not ring a bell...

Comment: Could you do this if you had the "maximum"-norm on the right-hand sude?